# Support Vector Regression (SVR) Time series

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, svm

I am trying to use SVR in python for a monthly time series.

My training data is from january 2019 to June 2021 and my testing from july 2021 to December 2021.

I am trying to predict the sales using not only the historical records, but also the prices for each SKU in each period.

Attached there are two images related to one of my products. One shows the sales and the other the prices.

[Sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNpqZ.png)

[Price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NO53.png)

My question is, how can I incorporate the prices as an exogenous variable? In SARIMAX it is easy because we have a parameter that account for exogenous variable, but in the case of the SVR I am not able to find it. The description below is from Scikit learn:

> sklearn.svm.SVR(*, kernel='rbf', degree=3, gamma='scale', coef0=0.0,
> tol=0.001, C=1.0, epsilon=0.1, shrinking=True, cache_size=200,
> verbose=False, max_iter=- 1)
>
> fit(X, y=None, *, groups=None, **fit_params)

How should I use fit in this case? Define as X a data frame with the prices and sales and as Y a series with the same sales? Or how should I tackle this problem?

Right now my X is a data frame of 30x2 (30 samples for price and sales) and my Y is a series with size 30 (the sales). This work when I am doing a grid search to find the best parameters. Here is my code for the grid search:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR

from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit, GridSearchCV

#Grid search

np.random.seed(1234)

C = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]

gamma = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]

SVR_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', cache_size=1500)

SVR_rbf_optimal = GridSearchCV(estimator=SVR_rbf, param_grid=dict(C=C, gamma=gamma), n_jobs=-1, cv=None)

SVR_rbf_optimal = SVR_rbf_optimal.fit(train[train['CTN']=='HX9004/10'][['Quantity Adjusted','Price']],train[train['CTN']=='HX9004/10']['Quantity Adjusted'].values).best_estimator_
```

The thing is that now I want to use those best parameters (SVR_rbf_optimal) to predict my sales in my testing set, but I dont know how to consider the price in that testing set given that now my X is a series of size 30 (Price) and not a data frame of 30x2.

If I do the following:

```
SVR_rbf_optimal.predict(test[test['CTN']=='HX9004/10']['Price'].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

I get the following error because now my X is only with price (I cant use sales because would be leakage).

```
ValueError: X has 1 features, but SVR is expecting 2 features as input.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are training on two features ('Quantity adjusted' and 'Price'):

```
SVR_rbf_optimal = SVR_rbf_optimal.fit(train[train['CTN']=='HX9004/10'][['Quantity Adjusted','Price']],train[train['CTN']=='HX9004/10']['Quantity Adjusted'].values).best_estimator_
```

(specifically, this part of your code):

```
train[train['CTN']=='HX9004/10'][['Quantity Adjusted','Price']]
```

Now, when you predict, you try predicting on only one feature (the one you set as a target during traning!), which causes the error.

To fix this, you need to run the svr on the input features:

```
SVR_rbf_optimal.predict(test[test['CTN']=='HX9004/10'][['Quantity Adjusted','Price']])
```

Comment: Hi @warped , the thing is that Quantity adjusted is the variable that I am trying to predict in my test set (the sales from july 2021 to december 2021).  I only have the exogenous price variable for those 6 months, so I dont know how I should incorporate the variables to make the model works.

Comment: @MIGB91 You use `Quantity adjusted` as input when training your model. How do you expect it to be an output of your model?

Comment: reading more this past hours I realize that what I should do is leave Quantity Adjusted as my Y, and as my X use Price and the lagged values of Y. My question now is, how do I determine which lag should I use to train my model?. Thanks!